# OpenOffice - Regex for reformatting line with word + numbers

Tags: regex, openoffice

I have a document with sections headed "Chapter 1"-"Chapter 45".  I want to make them all caps and all in bold font by using a regex.  I am stuck. I keep ending up with things like "CHAPTER "[0-9]" (replacing Chapter 8 and not bold). I tried searching for "Chapter .*$" (no quotes) to see if I could grab the line and not deal with the numbers, but that didn't work either.

Thanks so much!! I'm quite sure this is a quick fix, I just can't figure out the syntax.  I've not worked on OpenOffice for several months, so I'm rusty.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Which platform are you using OpenOffice on?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a paragraph style to the titles and format the paragraph style the way you want with CAPS and bold.
To open the style window, press F11, assign a paragraph style (double click on style name) (title 1 for example) to the titles and right click on the style name to modify it. You'll find the CAPS option under font effects tab and bold under fonts.

Comment: great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Why not ignore the numbers and just go for `^Chapter` -> `^CHAPTER` ?
Assuming that Chapter indeed starts at the beginning of the line, or else if it is centered with a tab, add the tab `\t` between the `^` and the search/replace string.

Once you converted the chapters to capitals, you can search for CHAPTER, replace it with CHAPTER, but now with the format Bold & Italic.

You can't use Regular expressions AND Format at the same time in edit/replace.